# how to have angularJS post data to MVC controller which redirects to a view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am posting some data to an MVC action method using AngularJS. This action method will either show its backing view or redirect to another page. Currently all that is happening is the data is getting posted but the redirect is not happening via MVC. I am getting this done using angular's window.location method. I want to know if there is a better way or if I need to post differently using Angular.

On page A I have angular scripts posting data to page B like below:

```
        serviceDataFactory.POST('http://localhost:1234/home/B', someData, pageConfig).then(function () {
            //on success
            window.location = 'http://localhost:1234/home/Index';
            },
        function() {
            //on error
            window.location = 'http://localhost:1234/home/B';
        });
```

This is my service factory

```
app.factory('serviceFactory', function($http, $q) {


        var service = {};

        //POST
        service.POST = function (url, postData, conf) {

            var d = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: postData,
                config: conf
            }).success(function(data) {
                d.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(error) {
                d.reject(error);
            });

            return d.promise;
        }

        return service;
    }
);
```

On Page B I want to redirect to another page. This is my page B in MVC

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult B(string someData)
    {
        //recieve string someData and perform some logic based on it
        .
        .     
        .
        if(boolCondition)
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        else
          return View();

    }
```

Here once Angular posts to the action method B, it executes all the code all the way till the `if(boolCondition)` statement. Since I am unable to have that redirect affected via MVC, I do that in Angular itself using the success or error block that the promise returns to.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this or if I am doing something wrong here or if this is the only acceptable way. How do I get angular to hand-off to the MVC action method and let further redirects continue from there only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `.success()` / `.error()` pattern with `$http`, because [this has been deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).  Instead, use `then()` with two arguments, the first argument being the success function and the second being the error function.

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

You do not need to promisify the result of `$http`, because `$http` returns a promise.  Just return `$http` from your service.

```
app.factory('serviceFactory', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {};
    //POST
    service.POST = function (url, postData, conf) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            config: conf
        });
    }
    return service;
});
```

Your Page A controller will work the same as before with this new simplified code.  At the server, be sure to emit a 500 http status code in cases where you want to trigger the

```
function() {
    //on error
    window.location = 'http://localhost:1234/home/B';
}
```

to run.  The 500 in the headers of the response will cause the AngularJS promise to run the second function in your controller.